# Unexpected space between spans

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

I built this button with transform and transition. But there is a tiny problem that I can't figure it out. I have for span to scale them when I want to hover the link. Each span have 25% of a link width. but there is a tiny space between span number 3 and 4.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/v7193m/pen/vYypBwe)

```
    body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    a {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 3px solid rgb(84, 7, 136);
    color: rgb(84, 7, 136);
    padding: 50px 80px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    h2 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    body > div {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
            .effect11 a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: -1;
    }
    .effect11 a {
    transition: all 1s;
    }

    .effect11 a span:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
    }
    .effect11 a span:nth-child(2) {
    left: 25%;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    .effect11 a span:nth-child(3) {
    left: 50%;
    transition-delay: 0.45s;
    }
    .effect11 a span:nth-child(4) {
    left: 75%;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
    }

    .effect11 a:hover span {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    .effect11 a:hover {
    color: white;
    }
```

[This is what happening that I don't want to appear (that little space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ap4h.png)

Comment: Works fine in Chrome and Firefox on windows machine. What browser are you using?

Comment: Pretty sure you issue is with your Text "Hover Me". It is messing with the <span> columns.

Comment: i tested on chrome and firefox and get same result

Answer (score 0):

Here add flex:1 and It should solve the problem

```
body > div {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex:1;
    }
```

Comment: It's wired. That does not work, but when Idecrease the size of the browser, It does not have any problem! (without flex:1 ). I don't know why this is happening in maximize.
By the way, It will work when I give it flex:1 in codepen !!!!

Comment: Well when I can check my code with codepen it works so I can not know what causes the problem in different browsers.